# Why is my D3 svg not showing on the screen?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, d3.js

Here is my code! I am using angular and d3 library to make a simple shape but nothing shows up on the screen.

pie-chart TS File:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css'],
})

export class PieChartComponent {
  svg = d3
    .select('#canvasarea')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 400)
    .attr('height', 100);

  circle = this.svg
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 200)
    .attr('cy', 200)
    .attr('r', 50)
    .attr('fill', 'blue');
}
```

pie-chart HTML File:

```
<div id="canvasarea"></div>
```

app-component.html:

```
<pie-chart></pie-chart>
```

Comment: The code you've provided is pretty sparse. Are you instantiating your class anywhere?

Comment: i just edited the question, but, the app-component.html file calls the typescript selector. This is just a starter code for my project and i am not sure why the svg is not rendering on the screen

Comment: Doesn't look like the circle has a radius i.e. an r attribute.

Comment: idk why it still doesn't work even after adding a radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention above indeed you need to add a radius with r attribute. And you also need the view to have been rendered in your angular component to add the svg and do the operation on it

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css'],
})
export class PieChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public svg: any = null;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.svg = d3
      .select('#canvasarea')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 400)
      .attr('height', 100);

    this.svg
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', 50)
      .attr('cy', 50)
      .attr('r', 20)
      .style('fill', 'blue');
  }
}
```